# Run ecto migration with non-standard path of repo

Tags: elixir, ecto

I have a "dummy" app in my mix app, so, it's first migration is placed in `test/dummy/priv/repo/migrations/20160323060044_create_user.exs`.

I want to run this migration, but it returns `11:19:20.647 [info]  Already up`, and this disappoints me.

Here is my `test.exs`:

```
config :ecto_state_machine, Dummy.Repo,
  adapter: Ecto.Adapters.Postgres,
  username: System.get_env("USER"),
  password: "posgtres",
  database: "ecto_state_machine_test",
  pool_size: 10,
  port: 5432,
  priv: "test/dummy/priv/repo/"
```

Here is my migration:

```
defmodule Dummy.Repo.Migrations.CreateUser do
  use Ecto.Migration

  def change do
    create table(:users) do
      add :state, :string, null: false
      add :confirmed_at, :datetime

      timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

I'm running

```
MIX_ENV=test mix ecto.migrate -r Dummy.Repo
```

and get annoying `already up` instead of migration. What's I'm doing wrong?

My attempts:

1. I tried to drop and re-create database, nothing happened
2. My another turn was to require the code. I tried to implement this in my `test.exs` or `dev.exs`, but I received `module Ecto.Migration is not loaded and could not be found

   `"test/dummy/priv/repo/migrations"
   |> Path.join("**/*.exs")
   |> Path.wildcard
   |> Enum.map(&Code.require_file/1)`
3. I also tried to create a fake migration by `MIX_ENV=test mix ecto.gen.migration f -r Dummy.Repo`, fill it with code which raise an exception, and than I had

   `MIX_ENV=test mix ecto.migrate -r Dummy.Repo # => 12:49:00.932 [info]  Already up`

So, it can't find a repo. Sad, but true

4. I also tried to load shell `MIX_ENV=test`, then invoke code from 2nd approach, then `Mix.Task.run "ecto.migrate" ["-r", "Dummy.Repo"]`. it returned :noop to me?
5. Github issue: https://github.com/elixir-lang/ecto/issues/1428

Comment: Have you created your migration using `mix ecto.gen.migration create_user`? This should always place the transaction where Ecto can read it.

Comment: Yes, I did it. Take a look at 3rd approach

Comment: Wow, I've been dealing with this for hours and hours. When I finally narrowed it down to the `priv` aspect (and consequently the troubleshooting was done), I finally came across your post of the exact same problem! If the `ecto.gen.migration` command works, then the `ecto.migrate` command should also work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jose Valim commented [at github](https://github.com/elixir-lang/ecto/issues/1428):

```
This is fixed in Ecto 2.0.0-rc. In previous versions, migrations would always have to be inside priv. We have removed this requirement in Ecto 2.0.
```